# Рассылка сообщений в группе вконтакте

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, sqlite3, рассылка

я написал бота для группы вконтакте на Python, обычный бот написанный на vk_api с базой sqlite3.вопрос заключается в том, можно ли как то реализовать рассылку сообщений только 
 тем пользователям у которых на пример выбран пол-мужской.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть в базе список пользователей, которые уже писали вашему боту, то попробуйте использовать вот этот метод VK API https://vk.com/dev/account.getProfileInfo
Там есть поле sex, сделайте в цикле проверку юзеров по этому полю, и отберите нужных.

Comment: В боте группы, подойдет вот этот метод https://vk.com/dev/users.get. В аргументе метода нужно будет указать поле, которое он должен вернуть.Оно идентично тому, которое я указал выше(sex).